# Handle incoming query params from firebase URL verification email in react with Router v4

Tags: reactjs, email, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-router-v4

I'm trying to set up an email verification using firebase. I can create the user and send the verification through this function.

```
const auth = (email , password , infoUser = {}) => (
firebaseAuth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
    .then(user=>{
        user.sendEmailVerification(actionCodeSettings(email))
    })
)
```

I get to receive the email, it looks like this:

```
https://myappp.com/_/auth/action?mode=verifyEmail&oobCode=ueqReEeaua738p128Z36KzVTQTMmL-wu7IP_NTwLD4YAAAFhZJY4pg&apiKey=AIzaSyC51jYpiVeLUNa-FWnYUTvGrkVtN8tuiig&continueUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fautobuses-usados-mx.firebaseapp.com%2F%3Femail%3Dluissantiagodev%40gmail.com
```

but cannot handle the url in my app, it send me to the error page.

Here's my action code that I use.

```
export const actionCodeSettings = (email) =>({
    url: 'https://myapp.com/?email='+email,
    handleCodeInApp: false
});
```

Comment: whats the error on the page it sends you to?

Comment: I've created a Error404 component and that's where the link directs me to, I tried out with different paths with the Route Component but it won't work.

Comment: is myappp.com your domain? If not, you need to configure your domain in firebase hosting for this to work as expected.

Comment: Try removing your domain altogether and make sure it works with the .firebase domain you get by default. If it works then you have isolated the problem to being a custom domain issue.

Comment: Could you show your router?

Comment: Thank guys for your support I could handle the error correctly with a custom Route, I've edited the question for further details. I'm currently working now with the params query parsing.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer, not as an edit to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the problem my adding this component

```
    import {Redirect, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
    import React from 'react'


class AuthRequiredRoute extends Route{
    render() {
        // call some method/function that will validate if user is logged in
        {console.log(this.props.location.search)}
        if(!this.props.logged){
            return <Redirect to="/login"/>
        }else{
            return <this.props.component />
        }
    }
}

export default AuthRequiredRoute
```

**Example:**

```
 <AuthRequiredRoute path="/verify" component={Confirm} logged = {this.state.authed}/>
```

This is how the link is structured in my email template

```
https://testing-app.firebaseapp.com/verify?mode=<action>&oobCode=<code>
```